# 2d face animation for 3d mesh going crazy

Tags: animation, texturing, unity

I'm currently animating 2 faces for my character, But when I want it to animate from frame 0 to frame 5,instead of 0,5, it goes like this: 0,1,2,3,4,5. How do I make it instantly go to frame 5?

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review. ~

Comment: In the Image Texture (that has the movie), set Frames at 1, Start Frame > 100 (a high value),  Offset > 0, keyframe the Offset, in the Timeline duplicate this keyframe and put the duplicated at the frame "n" that is supposed to be the last that will play this image, put your playhead at n+1, Offset> 5, keyframe, duplicate the keyframe and move it...

Comment: i don't get it.

Comment: Maybe this image will help? https://zupimages.net/up/23/32/wmy0.jpg

Comment: See my comment to your other posting (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/298794/cant-instantly-animate-2d-face-texture-on-3d-mesh) showing a tutorial for the answer.