# can't instantly animate 2d face texture on 3d mesh

Tags: animation, texturing, unity

I'm currently animating 2d face textures for my character with texture frame 0 to texture frame 10, But when I want it to animate from frame 0 to frame 5, instead of 0,5, it goes like this: 0,1,2,3,4,5. How do I make it instantly go to frame 5, instead of playing them all untill it reaches 5?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: There's a tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/ufvM2ixj2FI?t=1564) showing how to animate face expressions using an image sequence. The problem you're having can be sorted using the Graph Editor and is explained [here](https://youtu.be/ufvM2ixj2FI?t=1630) in the tutorial.